# Sum a column of arrays by element in pyspark - only using spark functions

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to sum the arrays within a column of arrays by element - the column of arrays should be aggregated to one array. The below code gives the desired result, [3,6,9], but it uses a UDF which causes OOM when scaled. I would like the same result but purely in Spark!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,ArrayType

def sum_arr_by_element(l):
    return [sum(x) for x in zip(*l)]

my_udf = udf(sum_arr_by_element, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

data = [
    ([1, 2, 3],),
    ([1, 2, 3],),
    ([1, 2, 3],),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["array_column"])

df.agg(F.collect_list("array_column").alias('all_lists')).withColumn('summed',my_udf("all_lists")).select('summed').display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("toto").getOrCreate()

data = [
    ([1, 2, 3],),
    ([1, 2, 3],),
    ([1, 2, 3],),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["array_column"])

df = df.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.selectExpr("id", "posexplode(array_column) as (pos, value)")
result_df = df.groupBy("pos").agg(F.sum("value").alias("summed_value"))
result_array = result_df.orderBy("pos").select("summed_value").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

print(result_array)
```

Comment: This solution works and scales for my use case - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that first aggregates the elements of the array row wise then collects the elements in the order of their position in the original list

```
df_result = (
    df
    .select(F.posexplode('array_column'))
    .groupby('pos')
    .agg(F.expr("struct(pos, sum(col) as col) as pos_col"))
    .agg(F.expr("transform(array_sort(collect_list(pos_col)), x -> x.col) as array_column"))
)
```

---

```
+------------+
|array_column|
+------------+
|   [3, 6, 9]|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the maximum power of arrays in spark.

if you have a grouping column, collect all arrays within the groups, and use `aggregate` function. the function will retain the element positions.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy(func.lit(1).alias('group')). \
    agg(func.collect_list('arr_col').alias('all_arrs')). \
    withColumn('arr_sum',
               func.expr('''
                         aggregate(slice(all_arrs, 2, size(all_arrs)), 
                                   all_arrs[0], 
                                   (x, y) -> zip_with(x, y, (a, b) -> a+b)
                                   )
                         ''')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+---------------------------------+---------+
# |group|all_arrs                         |arr_sum  |
# +-----+---------------------------------+---------+
# |1    |[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]|[3, 6, 9]|
# +-----+---------------------------------+---------+
```